# Loop through elements with jQuery, but act only if doesn't have a class

Tags: jquery

I have some divs that are collapsible by a click toggle.

CLOSED/COLLAPSED

```
<div class="item-group-condensed context_module     editable_context_module     has_requirements      student-view collapsed_module" aria-label="Service Desk Module" data-workflow-state="active" data-module-url="/courses/2/modules/37" data-module-id="37" id="context_module_37" style="">
```

OPEN

```
<div class="item-group-condensed context_module editable_context_module           student-view context_module_hover" aria-label="Practice Module" data-workflow-state="active" data-module-url="/courses/2/modules/40" data-module-id="40" id="context_module_40" style="">
```

When they are collapsed they have a class .collapsed_module

I want to loop through them and if they do not have that class do something. In my example below they are ALL red, not just the ones who are missing the class.

```
if (!$(".item-group-condensed").hasClass("collapsed_module")) {
    $(".item-group-condensed .ig-header span.ig-header-title span.name").css("color", "red");
}
```

Do I need to put this into an each()? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You should be able to use jQuery's `.not()` method http://api.jquery.com/not/

Comment: or simple css `:not()` selector

Comment: Thanks for the replies, I'm actually going to execute some code. Just wanted to show that I wasn't selecting them correctly with the colors of the text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `:not` selector:

```js
$(".item-group-condensed:not(.collapsed_module) .ig-header span.ig-header-title span.name")
  .css("color", "red");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item-group-condensed context_module     editable_context_module     has_requirements      student-view collapsed_module" aria-label="Service Desk Module" data-workflow-state="active" data-module-url="/courses/2/modules/37" data-module-id="37"
  id="context_module_37" style="">
  <div class="ig-header"><span class="ig-header-title"><span class="name">Name 1</span></span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="item-group-condensed context_module     editable_context_module     has_requirements      student-view" aria-label="Service Desk Module" data-workflow-state="active" data-module-url="/courses/2/modules/37" data-module-id="37" id="context_module_37"
  style="">
  <div class="ig-header"><span class="ig-header-title"><span class="name">Name 2</span></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Using this they are all black and none are red upon load.

Comment: Add the HTML to the question, and mark up which should be red or black.

Comment: added. Open should be red, closed should be black

Comment: I had a typo, `:item-group-condensed` should have been `.item-group-condensed`.

Comment: Just checking to see if I was paying attention eh!? Many Thanks, this will do the trick!

Answer (score 1):

Using just CSS:

```js
$(".item-group-condensed").click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("collapsed_module")
})
```

```css
.item-group-condensed.collapsed_module {
  color: black;
}

.item-group-condensed:not(.collapsed_module) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="item-group-condensed context_module editable_context_module has_requirements      student-view collapsed_module" aria-label="Service Desk Module" data-workflow-state="active" data-module-url="/courses/2/modules/37" data-module-id="37" id="context_module_37">
  Item 1
</div>


<div class="item-group-condensed context_module editable_context_module student-view context_module_hover" aria-label="Practice Module" data-workflow-state="active" data-module-url="/courses/2/modules/40" data-module-id="40" id="context_module_40"> 
  Item 2
</div>
```